# add a user to an group access

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to add a user on group that exist on res.groups
But i don't know why he does not add in this group 
This is my code python

```
class access_teacher1(models.Model):

 _inherit = 'res.users'

 def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):

    new_id = super(access_teacher1, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    if self.browse(cr, uid, new_id, context=context).is_teacher:
            self.write(cr, uid, [new_id], {'password': vals['login']}, context=context)

    res_groups = self.pool['res.groups']
    group_id = self.pool['ir.model.data'].get_object(cr, uid,'pronote','proschool_teacher')
    res_groups.write(cr, uid, [group_id], {'users': [new_id]}, context=context)
    return new_id
```

the problem stopped on   {'users': [new_id]}
how to fix that

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
res_groups.write(cr, uid, [group_id.id], {'users': [(4,new_id)]}, context=context)
```

The reason is that Odoo use an special command format to write values against the One2many and Many2many fields

You could read more about it at:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9e8f70e4849b0eeaca8b5cf51372ecfa23dc561b/openerp/models.py#L3724-L3761

Comment: always try to use permanent links. In Github just open your desired code, mark it and then use Y to change to url to a permanent url/link

Comment: he shows me that when i put ur code
openerp.sql_db: Programming error: can't adapt type 'res.groups', in query  SELECT "res_groups"."id" FROM "res_groups"
                        WHERE "res_groups".id IN %s  ORDER BY "res_groups"."name"

Comment: I have updated my answer to change group_id to group_id.id since ir.model.data get_object method return a record. That's why you are getting that error